# Tkinter - Iterate through mp3 files to edit tags

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning python/tkinter and as a project I am trying to create a GUI to edit mp3 tags.

I have a for loop that will go through all directories/files in a directory and for each file return the tags.
I also have a tkinter code that will create a window with labels, buttons and a text box to provide a new tag. Right now I am focusing on the genre tag but I plan to expand this as I continue to build this code.

I want a GUI that displays the tags from a file and allows for new text to be entered that will be written to the mp3 when I press the update button as well as getting the information on the next file in the directory to be edited.

Separately my codes are working.  When I try to put the os.walk loop into the tkinter mainloop it isn't working. I get the feeling that I am approaching this wrong.

Can someone help me understand what is wrong with my approach?

#### loop through files

```
import mutagen
import os

list_of_genres = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\Music'):
    for name in files:
        music_file = os.path.join(root, name)
        try:
            filetags = mutagen.File(music_file, easy = True)
            genre = filetags.tags['genre']
            list_of_genres.append(genre)
        except:
            list_of_errors.append(music_file)    
list_of_genres
```

#### tkinter gui

```
from tkinter import *

def click():
    #this collects the text from the text entry box 
    entered_text=textentry.get()
    output.delete(0.0, END)
    #try:
    #except:

def close_window():
    window.destroy()
    #exit() #### This will kill kernel

# main:
window = Tk()
window.title('Genre Editor v.0001')
window.configure(background='black')
# my photo
photo1 = PhotoImage(file = 'C:\Music\Blank 185\Dido Ranch\AlbumArtSmall.gif')
# create labels
Label (window, image=photo1, bg='black') .grid(row=0)
Label(window, text = 'Artist: ', bg='black', 
fg='white', font='none 12 bold').grid(row=1, sticky=W)
Label(window, text = 'Current Genre: ', bg='black', 
fg='white', font='none 12 bold').grid(row=2, sticky=W)
Label(window, text = 'New Genre: ', bg='black', 
fg='white', font='none 12 bold').grid(row=3, sticky=W)
# box for text input
textentry = Entry(window, width=30,
bg='white') .grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)
# action buttons
Button(window, text='Quit', width=15, command=close_window
).grid(row=4, column = 0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
Button(window, text='No Change', width=15, command='' 
).grid(row=4, column = 1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
Button(window, text='Update Genre', width=15, command=click
).grid(row=4, column = 2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
window.mainloop()
```

#### Attempt to mix the two

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import mutagen

def click():
    entered_text=textentry.get()
    output.delete(0.0, END)

def close_window():
    window.destroy()

# main:
window = Tk()
window.title('Genre Editor v.0001')
window.configure(background='black')
list_of_errors = []
list_of_genres = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\Music'):
    for name in files:
        music_file = os.path.join(root, name)
        try:
            filetags = mutagen.File(music_file, easy = True)
            photo1 = PhotoImage(
            file = 'C:\Music\Blank 185\Dido Ranch\AlbumArtSmall.gif')
            Label (window, image=photo1, bg='black') .grid(row=0)
            Label(window, text = 'Artist: '+ artist, bg='black', 
            fg='white', font='none 12 bold').grid(row=1, sticky=W)
            Label(window, text = 'Current Genre: '+ genre, 
            bg='black', fg='white', font='none 12 bold').grid(row=2, 
            sticky=W)
            Label(window, text = 'New Genre: ', bg='black', 
            fg='white', font='none 12 bold').grid(row=3, sticky=W)
            textentry = Entry(window, width=30, bg='white'
            ) .grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)
            Button(window, text='Quit', width=15, command=close_window
            ).grid(row=4, column = 0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
            Button(window, text='No Change', width=15, command=''
            ).grid(row=4, column = 1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
            Button(window, text='Update Genre', width=15, command=click
            ).grid(row=4, column = 2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
        
        except:
            list_of_errors.append(music_file)    

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with the code is the file loop. GUI applications are event based so the button must be used to move to the next file. For the controls, build them once then update the values when a new file is loaded.

Try this code. It loads the tag data into the form for each file.

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import mutagen

def click():  # next file
    global lblArtist,lblGenre,lblNewGenre,curFile
    entered_text=textentryVar.get()
    #output.delete(0.0, END)  # what does this do ?
    while curFile < len(lstFile):
        curFile += 1 
        try:
           load_file(curFile)  # next file
           break  # load success
        except Exception as ex:
           print("Load failed:", lstFile[curFile], ex)
           curFile += 1 # go to next file
    else:  # done files
        lblArtist['text'] = "--- Done All Files ---"
        lblGenre['text'] = ""

def close_window():
    window.destroy()

def load_file(i):  # load tags
   global lblArtist,lblGenre,lblNewGenre
   filetags = mutagen.File(lstFile[i], easy = True)
   print(lblArtist)
   lblArtist['text'] = filetags['artist'][0]
   lblGenre['text'] = filetags['genre'][0]
   lblNewGenre['text'] = ""

lstFile = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Music'):  # all files in folder
    for name in files:
        lstFile.append(os.path.join(root, name)) 

# main:
window = Tk()
window.title('Genre Editor v.0001')
window.configure(background='black')

# build form
lblArtist = Label(window, text = 'Artist: ', bg='black', fg='white', font=("times", 12, "bold"))
lblArtist.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
lblGenre = Label(window, text = 'Current Genre: ', bg='black', fg='white', font=("times", 12, "bold"))
lblGenre.grid(row=2, sticky=W)
lblNewGenre = Label(window, text = 'New Genre: ', bg='black', fg='white', font=("times", 12, "bold"))
lblNewGenre.grid(row=3, sticky=W)
textentryVar = StringVar()  # entry box needs linked variable
textentry = Entry(window, textvariable=textentryVar, width=30, bg='white' ) .grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2)
Button(window, text='Quit', width=15, command=close_window ).grid(row=4, column = 0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
Button(window, text='No Change', width=15, command='' ).grid(row=4, column = 1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
Button(window, text='Update Genre', width=15, command=click ).grid(row=4, column = 2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)

list_of_errors = []
list_of_genres = []

# start file counter
curFile = 0
load_file(curFile)  # load first file

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for to get me unstuck.  Many thanks!